# how to remove text drawn from Canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I want to remove text from `Canvas` that I have drawn by using following code.

```
   canvas.drawText(label, width / 4, height / 3, paint_text);
```

Once it is done, user can edit that text so I want to delete the already drawn text from canvas before edit it and write new text.

One thing I want to make clear that I write text on canvas with *image bitmap*.

Is it possible in any other way? Please help me solve this.

Comment: try this canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); // or BLACK what ever ur background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only way to remove text from canvas is to take one condition and if condition did not satisfied then do not draw these text. Generally we use canvas to draw continue-sly.

```
if(flag){
///draw text
}else{
//Do not draw
}
```

to call onDraw() method again to show new changes call inValidate() if you are in same thread or postInvalidate() from different thread

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you redraw every time the text is edited, this can be done by calling the invalidate() method in your setText() method. So let the user edit the text, then simply redraw the canvas:

```
public setText(String text)
{ 
     label = text;
     this.invalidate();
}

...
//inside your draw method
canvas.drawText(label, width / 4, height / 3, paint_text);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use invalidate(); see below example

@Override

```
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
```

//invalidate can remove then recreate another

```
        invalidate();
        // put your drawing commands here
        paintText.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paintText.setTextSize(Util.dpToPx(BaseActivity.this, OVERLAY_TEXT_SIZE_INT));
        paintText.getTextBounds(overlayText, 0, overlayText.length(), bounds);
        canvas.drawText(overlayText,
                getWidth() - (bounds.width() + TEN),
                this.getHeight() - OVERLAY_TEXT_SIZE_INT,
                paintText);

    }
```